# How to extract and split a string in multiple parts

Tags: python

I would like to search and split different files in a directory based on some pattern  which may contain different file formats:

```
/path/


somefile.txt 2010-01-01
file.txt 2010-01-02
f.txt 2010-01-03
test.txt 2010-01-04
photo.jpg 2010-01-04
script.py  2010-01-05
```

In order to get:

```
somefile.txt 
file.txt 
f.txt 
test.txt
```

Here first I would like to catch all files which contains .txt and split them accordingly:

```
def catch_txt(path):
    result = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if 
re.search(r"\w+\.\w+\txt", f)]
    splitted_result = [files for files in result if 
re.split(r"\w+\.\w+\txt", f)]
    # some other stuff
    return splitted_result
```

But only gives a emtpy list.

Comment: does `glob.glob('/path/*.txt')` not work ?

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: Is the result of os.listdir(path) is : "somefile.txt 2010-01-01" or "somefile.txt " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the .txt :

```
res = [ i.split(" ")[0] for i in os.listdir(path) if '.txt' in i ]
```

Comment: I might prefer `if i.endswith('.txt')`. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @erip Thanks, didn't know about this one !

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern:

```
r"\w+\.\w+\txt"
```

looks for:

1. A word character, one or more times, followed by...
2. A literal dot, followed by...
3. A word character one or more times, followed by...
4. A tab character, followed by...
5. The literal characters 'xt'.

So your pattern will match filenames like:

```
 hello.a    xt
```

If you want to match filenames like:

```
hello.txt
```

then you need to use a pattern like:

```
r"\w+\.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using `re`. Assuming your list of filetypes is short, you can just create a list for each filetype

```
import os 

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
txt_files = [] #create additional lists/loops for each filetype
for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            txt_files.append(file)
print (txt_files)
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you use a list comprehension in one case and an append pattern in the other case. Any reason you did that? Or why you didn't just consolidate them into a single comprehension? `txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.txt')]`.

Comment: @erip I like your more succinct solution!